# How to send alert every 30 second with pine script (tradingview)?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to send an alert every 30 second. but its not working how i expect.
sometimes its sending 3 alert in the same time.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='some indicator')
if (timenow % 30 == 0)
    alert('raise some alert', freq=alert.freq_all)
```

problem here is that tradingview runs the script everytime price changes.
so i changed the code to :

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='some indicator')
if (timenow % 30 <= 5 and timenow % 30 >= 25)
    alert('raise some alert', freq=alert.freq_all)
```

i can catch the ticker like this but the problem is sometimes im getting 2 or 3 alerts in the same time.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever the alert is shown then you can set a flag variable. And reset that variable when the duration ends. And for each valid duration you can check if the variable is set or not before displaying the alert. Example:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='some indicator')
varip alertshown=false
if (timenow/1000 % 30 <= 5 or timenow/1000 % 30 >= 25) 
    if not alertshown
        alert('raise some alert', freq=alert.freq_all)
        alertshown:=true
else
    alertshown:=false
```